# Hard Disk Data Analyser

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

Like wireshark for Network , do we have any tool for ubuntu to read and analyse the data on hard disk(Bit level).

Comment: What do you mean by *analyse*? What do you want to know?

Comment: Would you like to find out how many ones and zeroes are on the disk? ;-)

Comment: As in Wireshark we can see that which bits belong to IGMP or TCP etc, similarly I want to study the disk with all the details about the files on it eg. where it starts,it ends, or which type of byte information shows that here it is video, img, txt files.(also understanding the file deletion and recovery). Booting study, what happens at partition posiition...etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try TestDisk from CGSecurity (info [here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)). In the the link:
TestDisk can:
Fix partition table, recover deleted partition
Recover FAT32 boot sector from its backup
Rebuild FAT12/FAT16/FAT32 boot sector
Fix FAT tables
Rebuild NTFS boot sector
Recover NTFS boot sector from its backup
Fix MFT using MFT mirror
Locate ext2/ext3/ext4 Backup SuperBlock
Undelete files from FAT, exFAT, NTFS and ext2 filesystem
Copy files from deleted FAT, exFAT, NTFS and ext2/ext3/ext4 partitions.

It is OpenSource and can be run from:
DOS (either real or in a Windows 9x DOS-box),
Windows (NT4, 2000, XP, 2003, Vista, 2008, Windows 7 (x86 & x64),
Linux,
FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD,
SunOS and
MacOS X

Using the program you can see that it does indeed analyse the data. If you want to view it at bit level - which is an entirely different thing - just use dd to take a copy then use hexdump to view it.

I think you need to clarify your requirements.